# Optimizing Choice of Life Partner

Tags: probability, optimization

In this [link](https://www.ted.com/talks/hannah_fry_the_mathematics_of_love?language=en), Hannah Fry mentions that a mathematical argument has been made towards the probabilistically optimal strategy for picking someone to settle down with.

The claim is as follows:
If we pick a threshold $T$ to represent the time window with which you are suitable to date. If we look at the 'first $37$% of your dating window', you should ignore these people and then marry the 'first person who is better than anyone you've seen before.'

Clearly, there is an extreme lack of rigor in the above statement, but she is giving a lecture to the masses, so what can you really expect...

**My question becomes:**
She mentions there is theory behind this, and that it has a rigorous background. Is there a theorem, or statement about order statistics, probability or others which confirm or support this hypothesis? I've been trying to imagine an approach which is independent of probability distribution of 'partner ratings'. I feel this is the only way that you can make such a blanket statement about this strategy.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: A key point in the secretary problem as well as the thug problem mentioned by Mark Fischler is that each candidate that is rejected is not available for reconsideration any more. In the real-life version of the _(marriage)_ problem, a rejected candidate _can_ be reconsidered later and accepted, as in, for example, Jane Austen's _Pride and Prejudice._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia knows this as the [secretary problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem).

The famous 37% strategy (actually not exactly 37% but $e^{-1}$) is optimal in the particular sense that it gives the *highest probability* of ending up with the best suitor.

This sense of "optimal" contains the implicit assumption that "getting the second best" and "getting none at all" both count as losing and are worth nothing. In many real-life choice situation this assumption may not necessarily hold.

The derivation (which I'm not immediately able to reproduce) doesn't depend on a particular probability distribution on "partner ratings", as long as it's the same for all the interviewed partners, and the probability that two different candidates rate exactly equal is negligible. In this case, only the *ordering* between the ratings really matter, and instead of choosing random ratings we could start by listing everyone in order of desirability and then permute them randomly afterwards. So the problem is intrinsically a *discrete* one.

(The fact that "only the ordering matters" is also an implicit assumption, of course. If we relax it such that we can measure the exact rating of every interviewee -- and we can assume WLOG that it is normalized to be uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$ -- better strategies become available. For example if the first among 20 applicants turns out to score 0.999, it's overwhelmingly likely they're the best overall, and it would be a net loss to continue with the 37% strategy after that).

Comment: Thanks, your argument regarding the reduction of this problem to a discrete problem makes a lot of sense. I'm most interested in the derivation, however.

Comment: @jameselmore: There's a derivation in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I saw at the bottom it said that the solution tends towards $\frac1e$, but I realize now it's due to the integral approximation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as a more rigorously defined problem given by G. C. Rota in his MIT probability course in 1969 (I am sure it dates farther back than that):

A detective knows there are $N$ thugs in a house and that the leader is the tallest.  He wishes to tail the leader, but the thugs will come out in random order and if he tails one, he will miss the chances to tail any of the others.  How should he decide which one to tail, to maximize the likelihood that he will tail the leader.

The answer, rigorously, is to observe the first $N/e$ of the thugs, and then tail the next one that is taller than all the ones already observed.

I believe the problem was solved on the blackboard using only Stirling's approximatino for $n!$ and some fairly clever reasoning.

Comment: Very interesting (and more concise) redefinition of the problem. I'm interested in the derivation specifically, however